# What's the proper method of deploying the Corecon API with my app?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, emulation, corecon

I have a WinForms app that instantiates the WP7 emulator. Everything works great locally (of course). But I've created a VM to test installations and XCopies. Getting the following exception upon attempts to pull up the emulator with my app in the VM:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop.10.0, Version=10.0.0.0..."

I have the Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity assembly set to copy local, so it's along for the ride. But nothing else shows up.

I was looking for a Corecon API instllation that was separate from the Visual Studio install, but wasn't able to find one. Seems like that would solve my issue since the assembly in question is sitting in the GAC.

Am I going to have to resort to actually referencing this assembly manually in my project? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you managed to get this working? Moreover, have you managed to use the Smart Device Connectivity in your WinForms application on a client's system on which VS2008/VS2010 has not been installed? I'm planning on building a WinForms deployment application for helping clients install software on their device. But by the looks of it, having VS2008+ on the system is mandatory. Which would obviously be defeating the purpose.

Comment: @Cloud - You simply have to install the WP7 SDK for everything to run correctly. I was hoping to avoid that as it's quite the pain of a requirement. It would've been much better to allow specific assemblies to ride along on my installer.  :(

Comment: Well although that's not the answer I would like to hear, thank you anyway. It saves me a lot of trouble going down that path. I'll start by looking at other methods of deploying applications from Windows computers to connected devices. Having all our clients install the WP7 SDK is far from ideal.

Comment: @Cloud - Agreed. If you think about it, please post back here if you find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is running the emulator inside a VM.

The emulator is a VM and running it inside a VM is not offficially supported. Different people have had differing levels of success using different virtualization technologies so you may have success with a different one.

Comment: But therein is the overall question: How to deploy it to any machine, real or VM. I have to send this app off to my client. The VM was only a way to test the installation/operation of the app. Thus far all I see is that it comes with Visual Studio. But surely there's a way to take it along as well without manual intervention.